# Is it possible to use AWS Route 53 as a DNS provider for a bare-metal K8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-route53

I would like to use Route 53 as the DNS provider of a bare-metal k8s cluster. I've found a few guides on the internet, but they are all for cloud k8s clusters.

Have anyone done this before?

Comment: Do you mean for cluster DNS or via something like external-dns?

Comment: Hi, for external-dns. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to set this up on my on-prem K8s cluster. I used "external-dns" - running locally (https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns), and this is what I've done from the AWS side:

---

## On AWS

Create the following resources:

```
IAM user k8s-r53-user
IAM policy assume-role-policy (attached to the k8s-r53-user)
IAM policy allow-k8s-r53-connection
IAM role k8s-r53-role (allow-k8s-r53-connection policy attached to this role)
```

### 1 - Create IAM resource:

```
     $ aws iam create-user --user-name k8s-r53-user
```

### 2 - Create policy (pretty generic):

policy-document1.json

```json
        {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "iam:ListRoles",
                        "sts:AssumeRole"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*"
                }
            ]
        }
```

run:

```sh
$ aws iam create-policy --policy-name assume-role-policy --policy-document policy-document1.json
```

### 3 - attach the policy to k8s-r53-user:

```sh
$ aws iam attach-user-policy --user-name k8s-r53-user --policy-arn "arn:aws:iam::${account_id}:policy/assume-role-policy"
```

check:

```sh
$ aws iam list-attached-user-policies --user-name k8s-r53-user
```

### 4 - create an IAM policy which will be attached to the role.

policy-document2.json:

```json
        {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*"
                },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "route53:ListHostedZones",
                "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                "*"
              ]
            }
        
            ]
        }
```

run:

```sh
$ aws iam create-policy --policy-name allow-k8s-r53-connection --policy-document policy-document2.json
```

### 5 - Create IAM role:

application-role-trust-policy.json:

```json
        {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:root" },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
        }
```

run:

```sh
$ aws iam create-role --role-name k8s-r53-role --assume-role-policy-document application-role-trust-policy.json
```

### 6 - Configure k8s-r53-user on on-premise server

Create access keys for the k8s-r53-user:

```sh
$ aws iam create-access-key --user-name k8s-r53-user
```

- Use the values from the last command output and run:

```sh
$ aws configure
    AWS Access Key ID []: xxx
    AWS Secret Access Key []: xxx
    Default region name []:
    Default output format [None]:
```

---

## K8s side

Follow the guide on the External-Dns page, section "Running locally", the only part that changes is the end:

run:

```sh
$ builds/external-dns --registry txt --provider=aws --aws-assume-'role=arn:aws:iam::${account_id}:role/k8s-r53-role --source service --once --dry-run'
```

**instead of:**

```sh
$ external-dns --registry txt --txt-owner-id my-cluster-id --provider google --google-project example-project --source service --once --dry-run
```

---

## References

https://medium.com/@lvthillo/connect-on-premise-python-application-with-aws-services-using-roles-8b24ab4872e6

[External DNS official repo](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the config for external-dns is totally separate from how/where you run Kubernetes. The only thing you’ll need to do differently is create a dedicated IAM user with the right perms and plug the credentials into the right env vars. We do the same for our GKE clusters.

Comment: please provide details on these "right" perms and env